# Modify dijit.editor filters to allow tags

Tags: dojo

I am new to Dojo and am trying to use dijit.Editor.

I am able to successfully create my editor and am adding html to the editor  whenever someone pushes a button. For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true,parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* bring in the claro theme */
        @import "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script>
        function onDrag(event) {
            event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', 'Some content');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div  style="border:1px solid #000" id="myeditor" class="col-md-6 claro" data-dojo-type="dijit/Editor" data-dojo-props="extraPlugins:['foreColor','hiliteColor','|','createLink','insertImage','fullscreen','viewsource','newpage']">
    This is the <strong>default</strong> content.
</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <div id="btn" >BLAST</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    // Include the class
    require([
        "dijit/Editor",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/_editor/plugins/ViewSource",



            ]);

    require(["dijit/form/Button", "dijit/registry"], function(Button, dijitRegistry) {
        var button = new Button({
            label: "Click Me!",
            onClick: function(){
                var editor = dijitRegistry.byId("myeditor");
                editor.execCommand("inserthtml","<div>Here</div>");
            }
        }, "btn");
        button.startup();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the div tag is being stripped. What do I need to do to allow div tags to be inserted using the inserthtml command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dijit.Editor` does not filter your html string. The browser does.
For instance, in the editor start a bullet list. Then, when the cursor is on the first item of your list, press your button.
You will see that the `div` is there.
it have to do with the dom element you are currently editing.
If the cursor is inside a `div` and you insert a `div` it will be stripped.
Actually, if you edit a span and insert a span into it it is stripped as well...

Basically the browser tries to optimize the content.

There was an issue raised for chromium while many years ago: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122062

As a workaround, you can use a custom method to insert content. Like this:

```
    insertContent: function(content) {
        var insertRange;
            var selection = rangeapi.getSelection(editor.window);
            if(selection && selection.rangeCount && selection.getRangeAt){
                insertRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
                insertRange.deleteContents();

                var div = domConstruct.create('div');
                div.innerHTML = content;
                var node, lastNode;
                var n = editor.document.createDocumentFragment();
                while((node = div.firstChild)){
                    lastNode = n.appendChild(node);
                }
                insertRange.insertNode(n);
                if(lastNode) {
                    insertRange = insertRange.cloneRange();
                    insertRange.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                    insertRange.collapse(false);
                    selection.removeAllRanges();
                    selection.addRange(insertRange);
                }
            }
}
```

This method is copied directly from `dijit/_editor/RichText` (line 2161).
You can see a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/aqsL1mcf/